# How to process file having fixed width columns in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I would like to process below file:

```
01234000000000000000000+000000000000000000+
02586000000000000000000+000000000000000000-
12345000000000000000000+000000000000000000-
12122000000000000000000+000000000000000000+
```

I want to convert above file to:

```
01234,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000+
02586,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000-
12345,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000-
12122,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000+
```

Input file have fixed width columns 5,19,19 respectively.

I would like to solve using linux command.

I tried below command, but it is not working :(

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="5 19 19";OFS=",";}{$1="$1,$2,$3"}' data.txt
```

Executing above command on ubuntu 14.04 LTS  desktop OS, the output was nothing(blank).

Comment: You always stand a MUCH better chance of someone being able to tell you why a command isn't working if you tell us in what way `it is not working`, e.g. syntax error, core dump, incorrect output, no output, etc. and show us the undesirable output and/or error messages and include the OS and tool version.

Comment: @EdMorton  I have updated the question as suggested.. Thanks for your valuable feedback, I will surely follow your suggestions

Comment: It would help if you actually `print` the output.

Comment: Now you'd added the statement `the output was nothing(blank)` we could tell you that's because you don't have a `print` specified (e.g. `1` at the end of the script). We'd also point out that `$1="$1,$2,$3"` is assigning a fixed string to `$1` and what you were trying to do would be written `$1=$1","$2","$3` BUT that the right way to do it in awk is to do `$1=$1` and awk will automatically recompile the record for you. After that if/when that still fails, we'd just have to figure out which awk version you are using so you should have included that info right away too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt was quite close, although you forgot to `{print}`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="5 19 19";OFS=","}{$1=$1}1' file
```

`{$1=$1}` assigns the first field to itself, which is enough to make awk "touch" each record. I've used the shorthand `1`, which is the shortest true condition. The default action is `{print}`.

Note that `FIELDWIDTHS` is a GNU awk extension, so if you're using a different version, you will have to go with a different approach. For example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print substr($0,1,5),substr($0,6,19),substr($0,25)}' file
```

Comment: This is also not working:    Data in file is ==>
01234000000000000000000+000000000000000000+
02586000000000000000000+000000000000000000-
12345000000000000000000+000000000000000000-
12122000000000000000000+000000000000000000+

Comment: @user2123967 it works for me - are you using GNU awk? What does `awk --version` tell you?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 and on my terminal awk --version command says "awk: not an option: --version"

Comment: @user2123967: Try `gawk` instead of `awk`

Comment: @user2123967 On all Ubuntu I have used, `awk` points to `gawk`, so its very strange that you have some other.

Comment: @Jotne I think that relies on `gawk` being installed (I don't think that it is, by default).

Comment: @TomFenech: awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print substr($0,1,5),substr($0,6,19),substr($0,25)}' file worked for me :) Thanks for suggesting clean approach to solve this problem

Comment: @TomFenech `gawk` is default. I have installed more than 100 system since long time ago.  (Plain server install)

Comment: @Jotne gawk is not default in ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop OS. When I tried to run gawk it says "gawk
The program 'gawk' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gawk
"

Comment: @user2123967 I always use server. But you then now know what to install. :).  PS confirmed that Desktop does not have `gnu awk`, tested it now.

Comment: @Jotne I think Ubuntu 14.04 LTS comes with mawk(minimal awk) :( . I have to install gawk. Thanks Jotne :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -r 's/(.{5})(.{19})/\1,\2,/' file
01234,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000+
02586,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000-
12345,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000-
12122,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000+
```

Answer (score 2):

that would be very easy:

```
sed -n 's/\(.\{5\}\)\(.\{19\}\)\(.\{19\}\)/\1,\2,\3/p' your_file
```

what it does, is to capture each line by 5, 19, 19 then print it out with `,` in between.

```
$ echo 01234000000000000000000+000000000000000000+ | sed -n 's/\(.\{5\}\)\(.\{19\}\)\(.\{19\}\)/\1,\2,\3/p'
01234,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000+
```

Comment: Excellent...this works for me.. :) I have also changed option -n to -i for in place processing.

Comment: @user2123967 if you want to. note that it's pretty dangerous to do inplace modification.

Comment: That's a lot of slashes! Perhaps it would be worth mentioning the extended regex mode of sed, using `-r` (or `-E` with BSD sed).

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 'for $p (5, 25) { substr $_, $p, 0, "," }' data.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

this is suitable task for `cut` as well

```
$ cut --output-delimiter=',' -c1-5,6-24,25- data.txt
01234,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000+
02586,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000-
12345,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000-
12122,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000+
```

- `--output-delimiter=','` specify output field separator
- `-c` to select specified character(s)
- `1-5` first field
- `6-24` second field
- `25-` rest of the line

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/.0/,",0")sub(/+/,"+,")}1' file

0123,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000+
0258,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000-
1234,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000-
1212,000000000000000000+,000000000000000000+
```